# How to make Selenium IDE prefer name attribute over id attribute while recording?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, test-automation-framework

How to make Selenium IDE prefer name attribute over id attribute while recording?

This feature is needed when ids are auto generated by web framework.

Answer (score 1):

In Options|Options|Locator Builders there's a list of locator builders in order of preference which can be edited.

Selenium IDE 1.10.0